# model.hasMany is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

trying to access model from another js file in index.js file but got an error that **call.hasMany** is not a function. But if i put my all models in index file it works fine.But when i tried to access model from different js file it doesn't work and returns an error.

here is my main index file

```js
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('###############') // Example for postgres
const call = require("./models/call.model.js")
const session = require("./models/session.model.js")
const session_extra_data = require("./models/session_extra_data.model.js")
call.hasMany(session,{
    as: "sessions"
})
session.belongsTo(call,{
    foreignKey: "call_id",
    as: "call"  
})
session.hasMany(session_extra_data,{
    as: "sessionExtraData"
})
session_extra_data.belongsTo(session,{
    foreignKey: "session_id",
    as: "session"
})
call.findAll({
    limit: 5,   
    include: [{
        model: session,
        as: "sessions",
        indlude:[{
            model: session_extra_data,
            as: "sessionExtraData",
        }],
        required: false,
        nested: true,
        all: true
    }] 
    // include: [{
    //     all: true,
    //     nested: true
    // }]
}).then(data => {
    console.log("DATA", JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

and here is my call model

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const call = sequelize.define('call', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true, 
            field: 'id'
        },
        version: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
            field: 'version'
        },
        startDate: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            field: 'start_date'
        }
        
    },{
        freezeTableName:true,
        timestamps: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting an arrow function from different js file, but you're not returning anything in this function, so essentially, you have no access to the model that is being created inside this arrow function. You need to return your model in the function:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const call = sequelize.define(
        ....
    );
    return call;
}
```

then call this function in your index file to get the model returned:

```js
const call = require("./models/call.model.js")();
call.hasMany(...);
```

But I don't understand why you'd export arrow function from the js file, you've named the file call.model.js so I'm assuming you wanted to export the model itself. The right way to do this would be:

```js
const Call = sequelize.define('call', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true, 
        field: 'id'
    },
    version: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        field: 'version'
    },
    startDate: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'start_date'
    }
    
},{
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps: false
});

module.exports = Call;
```

Now your index file should work as it is.